# Why Qt5Multimedia.dll depend on Qt5Network.dll?

Tags: qt5, qtnetwork, qtmultimedia

I'm learning about Qt media in example "Media Player Example". When deploying, I saw that Qt5Multimedia.dll depend on Qt5Network.dll. Why? Can you help me to explain with other man about  this? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At least the QMediaPlayer can play things from URLs, so it has a dependency on the Qt5Network.

Comment: I know. But what it would do with an URL without the network?

Comment: for local file, there are many use cases of QUrl without network

Comment: And crash on a network URL, depending on how it's linked? It's not a proper API.